# Wordpress/PHP/MySql sort results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting

I have a query that loads values from the database based upon a province a user lives:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='provincie' AND ( ".$provincie_check.")";
```

This loads all provinces that a user holds.
Based upon this I load the users:

```
for($p=0; $p <count($personen); $p++){
    $persoon = $personen[$p];
    if ($p % 2 == 0){
            $oddeven = 'even';
        }else{
            $oddeven = 'odd';
        }
        $id = $persoon->user_id;
        $user_info = get_userdata($id);
        $p_fname = get_user_meta($id, 'first_name', true); 
        $p_fname = array($p_fname);
        sort($p_fname);
}
```

For every user I create a table to view them. I want them sorted upon ther first name. So I thought I create an array of all first names and sort that.
But no luck.

How can I sort the for-loop to view my users sorted by their first name?

Comment: This should be throwing an error `AND ( ".$provincie_check.")`. Unless you've got something for it that will valid syntax.

Comment: Nope no error you just missed a part of the code that provides `$province_check` it results `'meta_value' LIKE '%province%'`

Comment: I didn't "miss" it, you didn't provide that *important* bit of code in your question, that's why I said that.

Comment: I didn't say that you missed it by overreading it but missed it because I didn't provide it. However it's there now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don`t extract them directly with SQL?

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, meta_value as name 
          FROM $wpd->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key 
          LIKE 'first_name' 
          AND user_id 
          IN (SELECT user_id 
              FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
              WHERE meta_key='provincie' 
              AND ( ".$provincie_check.")) 
              ORDER BY name";
```

Comment: I like this. I will take a look. Thank you

Comment: This did the trick for me. However can you explain why I should change the * with theuser_id and meta_value. I thought they were used to get those values and nothing else